# Problem setting a private directory

Tags: 7, files

I have problems establishing a private files directory (D7.22)

I started at reading this article: http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/file.
I then created a `private` folder above the Drupal root, and entered its path `../private` at `admin/config/media/file-system`. Despite being warned about the performance implications, I chose the Default download method as `Private local files served by Drupal`.
Then, in a content type I created a native file field named Attachment, with Upload destination set to `Private files`. Widget: File.

At this stage I imagined that these settings would cause an uploaded file to go inside the `../private` directory. Nope, instead they go into public directory `sites/default/files`. Was my assumption wrong?

I tried the following debugging changes - but to no avail:

- changed `../private` to `sites/default/files/secure`
- changed field widget to Media file selector
- changed default download method to `Public local files served by Drupal`

Is it a site ghost? Am I doing anything wrong?
I really see no reason for this not to work. I'm close to filing a bug issue but would appreciate someone confirm that on their installation before I do so.

Comment: In my experience all you have to do is set the directory and make sure it is writable (I have used sites/default/files/private). Sounds like something strange going on.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using private upload on several sites and can confirm that this works.  So no need to file a bug issue.

> At this stage I imagined that these settings would cause an uploaded file to go inside the `../private` directory. Nope, instead they go into public directory `sites/default/files`. Was my assumption wrong?

No. This is indeed what should have happened.

So just to make sure, I set up a site to your exact specifications. I.e. with Drupal root in `/demo/drupal` and the private directory in `/demo/private`  (where `/` is the Unix *file system* root).

I first tested it using the absolute path (i.e. `/demo/private` as the private upload directory).  That worked without a glitch.

I then re-tested it using the relative path to the same directory (i.e. `../private`).  That also worked without a glitch.

I also noted that Drupal threw the following error if I tried to input a non-existing directory as the private upload directory:

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in drupal_mkdir()
 (line 2341 of /demo/drupal/includes/file.inc).
 The directory /demo/bogus does not exist and could not be created.
```

In other words: If Drupal allow you to use `../private` as the private upload directory without throwing this error, your setup *should* work for private upload.

Drupal will automatically place a `.htaccess`-file in the private upload directory to protect it against  prying eyes.  However, for best security, the private upload directory should be above the web-root.

PS: As for the file being "served merrily to an anonymous user", this will happen if the anonymous user is *granted* access to the *node* the privatly uploaded file it attached to.

All that the "private download method" does, is to extend Drupal's access control system so that files attached to nodes are made inaccesible to those who happen to know their URL.  It does so by pretending that the attachement is stored in the fictitious directory (`system/files/`).  Since this directory does not exist, bypassing Drupal by converting the path into an URL and requesting it directly from the web server will not work.

This is different from, and more secure than the "public download method". This method let those who know a file attachement URL bypass Drupal's access control.

Comment: Thanks Gisle, I hoped for your hint to work, but unfortunately - changing to`/demo/private` did not help. Changing the attributes from 755 (just as public files) to 777 did not help either.

Comment: `demo` is at root on my hosting. My installation is at `demo/drupal`. My private directory is as `demo/private`.

Comment: Thanks Gisle, in fact you helped a lot by confirming the setup. I set up a blank site too and the private folder was established successfully. However it behaved with one major glitch: the link to a private file, eg. `system/files/filename.jpg` was served merrily to an anonymous user (another browser). This is a no-no for production. And as I can't afford fighting this issue anymore at this time, I have written a small module which provides its own download callback using raw php code. Thanks so much again!

Comment: I guess moderator will soon ban us from further discussing the issue here. I will gladly grant you access to my site if you PM me, so that you will be able to see for yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a million. Simply putting the private folder under the sites/default/files folder did it for me, because really the private system of drupal put in an .htaccess file, that confuses anyone who tried to directly download the file using the url.
So for clarity, set up the private folder in media configuration to be :
sites/default/files/private
Greg